# Perfect image of locally finite closed coverings.

Tags: general-topology

Let  $A_i, i \in I$ is a locally finite closed covering of $X$ and $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map(closed continuous surjective map such that $p^{-1}\{y\}$ is compact for each $y \in Y$). Then is it true that the image of $A_i, i \in I$ is a locally finite closed covering of $Y$? 
How can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{A}=\{A_i:i\in I\}$, and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Each $x\in K$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ that meets only finitely many members of $\mathscr{A}$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite $F\subseteq X$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$. Let $U=\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$; $U$ is an open nbhd of $K$ that meets only finitely many members of $\mathscr{A}$.

Now let $y\in Y$, let $K=f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, and let $J=\{i\in I:U\cap A_i\ne\varnothing\}$; $J$ is finite. Let $C=\bigcup_{i\in I\setminus J}A_i$; $C$ is closed — why? — so $f[C]$ is closed in $Y$. Now consider the open set $V=Y\setminus f[C]$.